# FrameLayout which is offset re-positions itself when a Fragment is added to it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-view, android-fragmentactivity

I have a `FrameLayout` (within a `RelativeLayout`) to/from which I add/remove `Fragments` by means of the `FragmentTransaction` class. My `FrameLayout` is originally left-aligned with its parent and sometimes offset horizontally by means of the `FrameLayout.offsetLeftAndRight(int offset)` method.

I'm finding that when my `FrameLayout` is offset and I commit a fragment transaction to add a `Fragment` to it (i.e. `FragmentTransaction.add(R.id.myFrameLayout, myNewFragment).commit()`), my `FrameLayout` jumps back to its original location, ignoring its offset.

Anyone know why this is happening and how I can avoid my `FrameLayout` re-positioning itself when I add a `Fragment` to it?

> **Note:** I'm using the `offsetLeftAndRight(int offset)` method rather than the `setTranslationX(float translationX)` or other methods because I need what I'm doing to work pre-Honeycomb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by keeping tracking of the offset position and overriding my View's `onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)` method to offset my View appropriately whenever this method is called, as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
{
  super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);

  if (changed)
  {
    offsetLeftAndRight(myHorizontalOffset);
    offsetTopAndBottom(myVerticalOffset);
  }
}
```